gpart device busy trying to remove partition
The situation is the following:
# lsblk

DEVICE      MAJ:MIN SIZE TYPE               LABEL MOUNT

da0           0:92   36G GPT                    - -

  <FREE>      -:-    33M -                      - -

  da0p3       0:95  1.0G freebsd-swap  gpt/swapfs -

  <FREE>      -:-    37G -                      - -

md0           0:106 4.0G ufs                    - /

I want to delete da0p3. So I try that:
# gpart delete -i 3 da0

gpart: Device busy

Ok, maybe I need to turn off swap?
# swapoff /dev/da0p3

swapoff: /dev/da0p3: Invalid argument

So swap is already turned off. Maybe it is mounted somewhere?
# mount

/dev/md0 on / (ufs, local, soft-updates)

devfs on /dev (devfs)

Looks like it also isn't mounted. At this point I have no clue how to delete this partition. Any ideas?
I am running FreeBSD 14.1. I moved the filesystem to a RAM disk so I could delete the current filesystem and re-do it.

Looks like the ram disk was too big and the swap refused to turn off because of it
